# how do i get a game object to apply changes to a prefab in script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Using the Unity 3D editor. I have an object which changes colour when it collides with other objects, this all works, but when changing scene the ball reverts back to its default colour. So i need the ball when changing colour to update the prefab through the script so the other instances of the object in other scenes will also change colour.
here is the code i have written for the colour changing:

```
    using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class colourpicker : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject whiteblock;
    public GameObject limegreentintblock;
    public GameObject cyantintblock;
    public GameObject redtintblock;
    public GameObject yellowtintblock;
    public GameObject player;

    public Material limegreentint;
    public Material redtint;
    public Material cyantint;
    public Material yellowtint;
    public Material white;

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject == whiteblock) 
        {
            renderer.material = white;
        }
        else if (other.gameObject == redtintblock) 
        {
            renderer.material = redtint;
        }
        else if (other.gameObject == limegreentintblock) 
        {
            renderer.material = limegreentint;
        }
        else if (other.gameObject == cyantintblock) 
        {
            renderer.material = cyantint;
        }
        else if (other.gameObject == yellowtintblock) 
        {
            renderer.material = yellowtint;
        }
    }
}
```

thanks for any help in advance :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I were you I'd make a static class with an Empty Game Object where you can save the state of your object colour. In the Initialize part of you Ball you should check if a variable (that must be static as well) of this static class is different from an Initial state and then assign the colour of the static variable to the Ball object. This [LINK](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/323195/how-can-i-have-a-static-class-i-can-access-from-an.html) teaches you how to implement it (you have to change some stuff to make what you want achieve)

**EDIT**

In the static class you create something like

```
public static Material BallMaterial = null;   // or you can assign a Material that will act as InitialState
```

After that, in your piece of code, when you assign the new Material to the ball, you also assign the new material to *BallMaterial* and then when you load the new scene you check if the *BallMaterial* has a different value from its InitialState (or null).

Comment: okay i think i understood some of that, but i do not know how id save the state of the object colour into a variable

Comment: okay i have it all done, but when i change scene it still reverts back to white. i havnt done the check thing but dont really know how that works in the slightest

Comment: okay i just checked it works going into one scene just not the other so it works thanks :) i just need to play around :D